# JavaScript вывод из цикла

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы после каждого неправильного возраста он выводил окно `"сколько мне лет?"` до тех пор, пока тестируемый не угадает?

```
<script>
var a=prompt("Сколько мне лет?");
var b=28;
var b=a;
while(b<28) {
  alert("побольше");
  a++;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Составить алгоритм
2. Написать код

Начнем с первого.

1. Спросить "Сколько мне лет?"
2. Если ответ больше значения, вывести "Побольше". Вернуться к шагу 1.
3. Если ответ меньше значения, вывести "Поменьше". Вернуться к шагу 1.
4. Если ответ равен значению, вывести "Угадали". Закончить

Второй пункт:

```js
var trueAnswer = 28;
var answer;
do{
   answer = prompt("Сколько Вам лет?");
   if ( answer < trueAnswer )
      alert("Больше");
   else if ( answer > trueAnswer )
      alert("Меньше");        
}while ( answer != trueAnswer )
alert("Угадали!");
```

Comment: Спасибо!то что и ждал!написали о объяснили!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
function HowMuch(){
    prompt('Возраст?') == 28 ? alert('Верно!') : HowMuch();
}
HowMuch();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var old = 28;
var stop = false;
while (!stop) {
  var a = prompt("Сколько мне лет?");
  if a = b {
    alert("Правильно!");
    stop = true;
  } else {
    alert("Попробуй еще раз!");
  }
}
```

Comment: не работает!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function foo() {
  var a = prompt("Сколько мне лет?");

  if (a < 28) {
    alert("больше")
    foo();
  } else if (a > 30) {
    alert("меньше")
    foo();
  } else {
    alert("угадал!!!")
  }
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
while(prompt("Сколько Вам лет?") != 28) alert("Неверно");
```

Comment: не работает!!!!

Comment: @Verzilamv что именно не работает?

Comment: @torokhkun, "person is not defined"

Comment: @Verzilamv согласен, это я недопереписал, уже работает. Хотя Вам и так уже примеров насыпали :)

Comment: спасибо за помощь!